# How to take random rows from database, so that they are not duplicated, throughout multiple calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, random, guid

The problem is:
I'm using C# + EF, and I need to take 20 random entries.
After each next call, i need to append 20 more entries, randomed, but that weren't included in any previous function call.
Is there any way to generate GUID based on seed, so that it would generate identical guids throughout all the calls ?

Comment: You could simply keep open the query to the DB, without closing it. You read 20 rows, return them while keeping open the reader/ienumerable, then on request read the next 20 rows and so on.

Comment: @xanatos The problem is, that it's not for personal use, and i can't actually keep database opened. That's more like database used by server.

Comment: Let me comprehend, between the first 20 rows and the second 20 rows, how much time would it pass?

Comment: @xanatos it could be 10 seconds. It could be 10 minutes. And between the calls, 100 new users could log in, and request access to the db.

Comment: If it is a systemwide-query (so that there is only one), then there is little-to-no-problem I think. If it is user-dependant and user-connected (so that each user could launch it), then you are right this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to execute the query more than once, you can't order by `newid()` because it's random and you won't have the same result for the next execution.

So you need to have a pseudo random value. Hash is a kind of pseudo random value. Let's order by hash value.

```sql
DECLARE @randomKey nvarchar(max) = 'randomValue';
SELECT *,
       HASHBYTES('SHA1', @randomKey + cast(rowId as nvarchar(max))) as [Order]
FROM dbo.Table
ORDER BY [Order] DESC
OFFSET  5 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Using this code the result will *randomly* be ordered by `@randomKey`.

In order to let Entity Framework generate the `HashBytes` call for you, without writing T-SQL. You can have a look at this project : [Store Functions for Entity Framework Code First](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 1):

**can't be used because the prerequisite is to not keep the connection open**

As I've said in the comment, you could simply keep open the query to the DB, without closing it. You read 20 rows, return them while keeping open the reader/ienumerable, then on request read the next 20 rows and so on.

```
public IEnumerable<YourObject[]> GetRows()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select * from [yourtable] order by newid()";

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var lst = new List<YourObject>(20);

            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    if (!reader.Read())
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    var obj = new YourObject();

                    // Read your row
                    lst.Add(obj);
                }

                if (lst.Count == 0)
                {
                     break;
                }

                // Micro-optimization: we don't keep two copies
                // of the lst after the yield
                bool last = lst.Count != 20;

                var array = lst.ToArray();

                lst.Clear();

                yield return array;

                if (last)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```